# TypeError: DecisionTreeClassifier() is not an estimator instance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, typeerror, sklearn-pandas

The original 'model' was a numpy.float dataframe and when i run it, it gave the error -> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "numpy.float64") to str. So i turned model into a str, but now I get this. I am relatively new to Python. Any explanation/help pls?

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier  


f = pd.read_csv("vgsales.csv")
f = f.round(0)    

X = f.drop(columns = ['Rank','Name', 'Platform', 'Year', 'Genre','Publisher','JP_Sales','Other_Sales', 'NA_Sales'])[:11]
y = f['Year'][:11]

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()   
model.fit(X, y)

modelstr = str(model)
tree.export_graphviz(modelstr, out_file = 'FirstModel.dot', 
                     feature_names = ['EU_Sales', 'Global_Sales'], 
                     class_names = sorted(y.unique()), 
                     label = 'all',
                     rounded = True,
                     filled = True)
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359146/why-should-i-post-complete-errors-why-isnt-the-message-itself-enough and show us the error messages rather than describing them.

Comment: You shouldn't stringify the model. The first error message may be because your `class_names` are not strings (which the traceback, or an example of the data, would allow us to check).

Comment: Thanks Ben! Your answer led to the solution, the class names was float data so i switched it to a strings one. Now it's working awesomely and also managed to get a visualisation of the decision tree, thanks !